# CMFCEditBrowseCtrl flickering button icon

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2022

Similar question here (https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?540443-CMFCEditBrowseCtrl-flickering-button-icon).

I have a simple control on my dialog:

Simple dialog:

```
IDD_DIALOG_IMPORT_FROM_CLM_EXPLORER DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Import from CLM Explorer"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,198,155,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,252,155,50,14
    LTEXT           "Language:",IDC_STATIC,7,39,35,8
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST_LANGUAGE,7,54,142,115,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Students Database (CSV):",IDC_STATIC,7,7,85,8
    CONTROL         "",IDC_STUDENT_DATABASE,"MfcEditBrowse",WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x880,7,18,295,14
END
```

The variable mapped to standard control and customised in `OnInitDialog`:

```
m_browseStudentDB.EnableFileBrowseButton(_T("CSV"), _T("*.CSV|*.CSV||"), OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST);
```

- Windows 11
- Visual Studio 2022

---

Sample recording to explain what I am seeing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3wxN.jpg

---

I created a empty dialog project, dragged in the control and simply ran it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLdir.jpg

Flickers.

Temporary link to the project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kskhzntg3l4103u/MFCApplication9.zip?dl=0

Comment: What happens if you replace your `CONTROL...` resource with an `EDITTEXT IDC_STUDENT_DATABASE, 7,18,295,14, WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x880`? (Not sure off-hand what the 0x880 does - maybe you can clarify?)

Comment: @AdrianMole It is not a "Edit" control. If is a "MFC Edit Browse" control so it has extra settings, like "Browse Mode" in the IDE. I guess that it what that value is. Although I override it in code because I need to set the file type filter. Simply drag a control of this type into your dialog and run it with no changes, and move your mouse over the control.

Comment: I know the difference. However, in my projects, I use an `EDITTEXT` resource for `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` controls; I even add 'edit box' styles, like `ES_LEFT|ES_AUTOHSCROLL` and those are applied correctly.

Comment: I just tried adding such a control in a dummy dialog project. I see no flickering - but I'm on Windows 10 and VS2019. Maybe it's a system DLL or VC-redistributable issue?

Comment: @AdrianMole The flickering is only on the icon on the right.

Comment: @AdrianMole And surely the RC file should be correct set via the IDE in this instance without the need to change it to a `EDITTEXT`?

Comment: Well, Andrew, I have created a dialog-based app using VS 2022 on Windows 10 and Windows 11 with the default settings. 
No flickering. It must be something you have changed that causes flickering. 
Would it be possible for you to deliver an application that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: @JohnCz are you using dark theme on windows?

Comment: No, custom theme. Why?

Comment: @JohnCz I was using dark theme. It seems sporadic. Sometimes there is no flashing but if I move mouse over the icon and not click and then move elsewhere on dialog it does flicker a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to dark theme, still no flickering. Tried 64 and 32 build debug and release, no flickering.
This is all I can to help do without the ability to duplicate this problem. Sorry.

I would check if any recently installed app running in the background or recently updated drivers are causing it. Try to restart windows in safe mode.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it in safe mode and report back.

Comment: Hi. I booted Windows 11 into Safe Mode and it did not flicker. I then restarted normally and it seems OK. Atleast the release build (outside of VS Studio environment).